# How can i list all branch lists in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, svn

I am coding a script that makes a comparison between two repositories from two different source control systems (svn and git) for a work I'm doing.

In svn I just took the link of the repository that is the same as I would need to checkout (pull) the branch or even the trunk (master) of it. But in git things look different and i only have a ssh link to do it, and for what I've seen so far nothing is really helping, i even tried to make a variable that was supposed to go to where the ".git" archive is setup in my machine to do the git branch -a from there, because I have seen it work when I'm inside the directory using the "WSL".

In svn I did it like this

```
svn_trunk="https checkout link"
BRANCHES="branches"
TAGS="tags"
TRUNK="trunk"

# Branchs Configuration
SVN_BRANCHES=$BASE_SVN/$BRANCHES
SVN_TAGS=$BASE_SVN/$TAGS
SVN_TRUNK=$BASE_SVN/$TRUNK
```

```
echo '[RUN] svn ls ' $SVN_BRANCHES
svn ls $SVN_BRANCHES
```

```
echo '[RUN] git ls ' $GIT_LIST
git tag -n $GIT_LIST
```

the out puts asks for my credentials and then it shows all the branches from it, but I don't know how to make something similar in git way.

I tried doing something similar to this:

```
GIT_BRANCHES=$GIT_URL/$BRANCHES
GIT_TAGS=$GIT_URL/$TAGS
GIT_TRUNK=$GIT_URL/$MASTER

echo '[RUN] git ls ' $GIT_BRANCHES
git branch -a $GIT_BRANCHES

echo '[RUN] git ls ' $GIT_TAGS
git tag -n $GIT_TAGS
```

and I was expecting that the exit listed all branches and tags out of the repository, what it isn't doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `git` commands in a repository, then `git branch -a` will output all the branches. For example, check the output of these commands:

```
git branch -a > mybranches.txt
cat mybranches.txt
```

Note that you don't need to specify anything after the `git branch -a` command if the current directory is a git repository.

But if your current directory (pwd) is not your git repository, then you may run the following command (note the `-C` option and a path):

```
git -C "PATH/TO/GIT-REPOSITORY" branch -a
```

The syntax is awkward. You have to add `-C PATH` before the actual `branch -a` command.